# How can I show a set of images as a slide show in android? 

Tags: android

How can I show a set of images as a slide show in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a range of apps that can do that. eg [Multi-touch Gallery](http://www.appbrain.com/app/multi-touch-gallery-for-droid/BandB.Lifestyle.Gallery.Multi.Touch).

You might find [android-slideshow](http://code.google.com/p/android-slideshow/) source code useful.

There is a default Android Gallery app, at least on my Samsung Galaxy S. It really bugs me that no generalisations can be made with Android phones, since all the carriers and manufactures customise them. Grrr... HTH

[This is the one I'm referring to](http://phandroid.com/2010/06/30/rumor-android-3-0-gingerbread-details-outed-1ghz-minimum-specification/)... can't seem to find much info on it anywhere, tho.

> "take a look at the Gallery app that comes with Android 2.1"

Answer (score 0):

There's no full-featured Android API component for that. You'll have to code a lot.